# Iteration in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use wrapAll to create a new wrapping div around several other div tags that has the same class, but it's not working as I want?

```
for (x=20; x<=42; x++) {
$(".c50:eq(" + x + ")").wrapAll("<div id='wrapper_datortillbehor'>");
}
```

Comment: How _do_ you want?  How _is_ it working?

Comment: What is it currently doing and what do you want it to do? Also, a HTML sample or jsfiddle link will help people trying to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(".c50").slice(20,42-20).wrapAll("<div id='wrapper_datortillbehor'>");
```

Comment: I think that will only wrap elements at index 20 and 21 because slice's second argument is the [end] index (which is not included). I think it should read `slice(20, 42)`